# Is this a Linear Programming Question?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

There are 4 States in a Country, S1, S2, S3 and S4.
Money (M) is to be split across these States through 5 Banks, B1, B2, B3, B4 and B5.

Each Bank has a limit to money it can keep, BL1, BL2, BL3, BL4 and BL5 respectively. 
1
BL1+BL2+BL3+BL4+BL5 = M

Each State has a neediness index which define the proportion in which money has to be split across the States S1:S2:S3:S4 is 0.2:0.4:0.3:0.5
This is a soft-limit, and delta variations in limit can be tolerated.

How does one split the money across the banks, such that the Banks are able to honour their limits and at the same time the States get money according to their relative needs?

I don't know how to approach this problem. My first hunch as a programmer is to apply a Genetic algorithm and ensure in the fitness that the proportions between the States are best maintained according to their needs.

But is their a more cleaner way to solve such a problem? My initial Googling suggests that Linear Programming might be an elegant way to solve such questions.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Apologies for the badly written title.

Disclaimer: It's not a homework question.

Comment: I see $S_5$, so there are $5$ states or is it supposed to be $B_5$?

Comment: My bad -- there are only 4 States. Corrected my mistake.

Comment: You could maybe tackle this as an assignment problem.